# How to get column difference between 2 rows in DB in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a schema that looks like this

```
id, time, child_id
```

so its something like

```
1, 15, 2
2, 19, nil
3, 20, 5
4, 1, nil
5, 100, nil
```

I need to get the difference between the time of the parent and its child

so for the above data the result would be

```
id | time_difference
-------------------
1  |  4
3  |  80
```

so if a row has a child, it would take the child's time and subtract it from the parent. Assume that children don't have children of their own (a row is either a parent or a child)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you only have a single level of parent/child, this can be done with a self join:

```
select p.id, 
       c.time  - p.time as time_difference
from the_table p
  join the_table c on c.id = p.child_id
where p.child_id is not null;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e882e/1

Comment: The `where` condition is redundant; you are doing an inner join.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: you are right (although I do think it adds some kind of "clarity" to the statement: "we are only interested in...")

Answer (score 0):

This approach let you choose the time unit of difference,  say you want your time difference in seconds, minutes, hours.  
**mysql** has an issue with time differences that hasn`t been fixed since long time ago.:

```
    Select
    a.id,   Time_To_Sec(b.time) - Time_To_Sec(a.time) As time_difference
    From   your_table a Left Outer Join
    your_table b On a.id = b.child_id 
    Group By 1
```